# Is right rudder always needed during go-around/touch and go with a Diamond DA-40?

Tags: landing, pilot-technique, rudder, diamond-da40

Is application of right pedal always necessary in parallel with advancing power lever in diamond aircraft (DA-40) during go-around/touch and go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"More right rudder" is like a Flight Instructor's mantra, for most all small single engine planes where the propellor spins clockwise from the pilot's viewpoint, and right rudder is needed when engine power is suddenly increased to counter the engine torque and airflow effects.